# Convenient notation for "is linearly proportional to"

Tags: notation

Is there a convenient notation for "$A$ is linearly proportional to $B$"? I know that you could write something like $$\exists k,c\in \mathbb R : A = kB+c$$
but I'm thinking something along the lines of $A \sim B$ or $A \propto B$. I just want something that I can write quickly many times. I'm working with a model that has a lot of relationships like this, so it would be convenient to have this kind of notation.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a universally accepted notional for "affine proportionality".  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063568/notation-to-express-affine-relationship) for a duplicate.  Of course, in any given paper you can introduce a notation, so long as you define it clearly.

Comment: Thanks lulu, I was trying to find a duplicate question but didn't see that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notation to express affine relationship](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063568/notation-to-express-affine-relationship)